# QGIS Visibility Analysis > Viewshed: results appears not in all directions

Tags: qgis, raster, viewshed, visibility

I am trying to analyse the visibility of a particular tower of a castle from the surrounding area. I have a Digital Surface Model (not DTM) which includes the built form (and therefore as I understand it, the observer height has been kept at 0).

The DSM looks like the below with the observer location / viewpoints in the SW corner of the castle:

[image: Original DSM]

The 'Create Viewpoints' dialogue has been completed as per the below, with no inputs for the azimuth optional fields.

[image: Create Viewpoints dialogue]

When I process the Viewshed however, I get the following output which appears directional. (There aren't any large objects that would obscure c.270 degrees and I've tried artificially raising the observer height in case the point was somehow sat in a localised divot in the DSM but I get the same result...

What am I missing?

[image: Viewshed Output]

Comment: On your screenshot, your tower has a height of 0?!? And I think you mixed target and observer height!

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem

As mentioned in @katagena's comment: the tower has a height of x (20m? 50m? 70m?) and hides everything that is behind it. That's why you don't have any results there.

And: if you set an **observer height** of 0, that means your result shows what can you see from the ground: either the ground of the tower's top platform or - if shifted just a few meters - next to the tower's base on the earth - but in any case in an ant's perspective of if you are lying on the ground. A person normally has their eyes at a height above ground of ca. 1.5 to 2 m.

*Sketch: O= observation point at height 0 (on the ground at the towers ground point), objects 1 to 4 with the part that can be seen from O highlighted; rooftop of object 4 is below sightline and thus invisible fom O (covered/hidden by object 3 respectively 1 and 2); however, the top of an object on this roof is visible if it has a certain height that projects above the line of sight above rooftop 3:*
[image]

*The same setting, with observer hight at the top of the tower (observation point O2): additional parts of the digital elevation model's surface become visible (marked with the red circle in case of the first object/hill). In case of object/house no. 4, not only the top of the antenna/human being is visible, but the whole antenna/person plus a part of the rooftop:*
[image]

#### Solution: Observer height

With a viewpoint of 0 m for **observer height**, you'll probably only see some rooftops (as your result indeed shows). So inversely, only from these rooftops can the **base** of the tower (where it meets the ground) be seen: that's what your result shows. More precisely: it shows from where the SW corner of the tower's base can be seen: not from the NE, of course, as the tower itself covers this ground corner.

You, however, want to know where the **tower as such** can be seen, be it even only a part of it (the top). So repeat your analysis with the height of the tower as viewpoint to get a result that shows what can be seen from the top of the tower. Inversely, that also means: the resulting areas (what can be seen from the tower) are also the areas from  where the top of the tower can be seen.

You might also want to define "the tower to be visible means that at least the upper half or upper 30% of it are visible" - so in this case, define the viewpoint's height with that amount of the tower's height: 50% or 70% in the examples mentioned before.

#### Target height

The **target height** should also have the same height (eyes above surface). A target height of 1.8 m means: even if you can't see a rooftop/ground point itself from the tower, when there is installed an object (e.g. antenna) on this roof/groundponit with a height of 2 m, you could see the top 20 cm of it. Same is true for eyes above ground: with a height of 1.8 m for target height means: even when from the rooftop/groundpoint itself (lying flat on the roof/ground), you don't see the tower, when standing up with your eyes at 1.8 m (a tall person!), you can see the tower.

#### Tower's footprint

If the tower's footprint (the area of the platform on the top) is large, you will get slightly diffent results, dependig from where on the tower's platform you are. So you should repeat the analysis (or run your workflow it in batch mode) to get at least four viewpoints at extreme points (e.g. the four corners) of the tower. Then compare and/or combine the results, e.g. using raster calculator.

This is even more true if you run the analysis with an observer height of 0 (what you did) - than you must run it from differant sides of the tower because the tower itself always will cover a part of the viewshed.